# GPLv3 With Section 7 Exception Linked to LGPLv3

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility

As a follow up from [GPL V3 with OpenSSL Exception](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/2233/3570), I'm curious about linking an LGPLv3 project with a GPLv3 project that has a special exception for OpenSSL. In the answer to the aforementioned question, it was stated:

> Note, however, that you can only add exceptions to work for which you
>   have copyright control. If you want to include a third-party
>   GPL-licensed library in your project, you cannot make that library
>   adopt the exceptions present in your project.

This makes sense, obviously I can't and shouldn't modify the License for another person's copyright. That being said, I'm curious if I could link a LGPLv3 license with a GPLv3 license that is modified with exceptions? I suppose a simple way to answer this would be to check for compatibility between OpenSSL and LGPLv3. Thus far I've found nothing, so I've posted here. Will update with any new information.

Comment: Excellent question. From the perspective of "what grounds would there be to sue me?" it looks like there's *probably* none. With a GPL library, the author would say, "Hey, if you want to allow linking to OpenSSL, that's your business for your own code, but **I** never gave permission do that for my GPL library." However, in the case of an LGPL library, that's *exactly* a permission the author gave. To be sure, though, I'd ask the FSF Licensing Team (`licensing@fsf.org`). (On a personal note, I like to drop a few bucks in their [donation jar](https://my.fsf.org/donate) whenever I do.)

Comment: @apsillers Thanks for the suggestion(s). :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire if you get an answer, please share it here.

Comment: @vonbrand I've emailed them asking. I'm not sure if this is an issue at all, being that its LGPL and I'm just linking against it, not merging sources in. I'll post any other information I get.

Comment: @apsillers, you essentially say they won't sue, not that a suit would be thrown out as meritless/no standing

Comment: @vonbrand I meant to communicate that I think they'd lose their suit if they tried to bring the same complaint for use of their LGPL library as the (probably successful) quoted complaint I suggested for a GPL library. I probably could have made that clearer (and maybe there's a formulation of a complaint that *would* be valid for an LGPL library that I haven't thought of.)

Comment: @apsillers, you seem to consider the case where both copyright holders are the same, e.g. the FSF

Comment: I still have not heard back from FSF, but I think this question is kind of.. pointless. I think it only logical that since the LGPL is compatible with proprietary licenses when linked shared, there would be no interference or violation in the case that the linking project is GPLv3 + Special Exception. I think I only asked this because I had a headache from combing over piles of license compatibility papers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized after posting this question that, due to how permissive the LGPLv3 is, this was probably a non-issue. However, I still asked the FSF for official comment, and I received the following response:

> Once you've added the exception, you cannot link to other GPLv3
>   software which do not carry such an exception. If this wasn't the case
>   it would be trivial to circumvent the terms of the GPL for providing
>   the complete corresponding source code for a work by just writing a
>   trivial piece of bridge/wrapper/shim code, add an exception to that,
>   and then link to anything you wanted through it.
>
> However, LGPLv3 licensed code already has a broad exception to its
>   terms and shouldn't be an issue as long as you abide by the terms of
>   the license.
>
> I hope this is of help.
>
> P.S. I don't know if it's relevant in your case, but the FSF
>   recommends using GNUTLS instead of OpenSSL in software you write.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Donald R. Robertson, III,
>   J.D. Copyright & Licensing Associate 
>   Free Software Foundation
>   51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor
>   Boston, MA 02110, USA

So there you have it, there's no concern with GPLv3 exceptions conflicting with the LGPLv3.